# When I try to scaffold in ASP.NET I get the error: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, identity, dbcontext, scaffolding

The full error is:

```
Unable to create an object of type 'UserDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 StackTrace:
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate 'WebApp.Data.UserDbContext'.   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
```

I get this error whenever I try to scaffold a razor view. When I build my application or add a migration, I dont get any errors.

These are the services in my startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddDbContext<DataDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataDbContextConnection"), mig => mig.MigrationsAssembly("WebApp.Infra")));

services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        Configuration.GetConnectionString("UserDbContextConnection")));

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

services.AddRazorPages();
```

Everything works fine except for creating new razor pages using scaffolding. At first I got the error that I had more than one DbContext named UserDbContext in my project, but this got fixed by moving the AddDbContext service from IdentityHostingStartup to Startup. After I tested if I could scaffold, I got this error.

I use the identity library for login and users are stored in a different database. Thats why I have 2 DbContext in my project.

What could be the issue here? If you need more info, let me know.

UserDbContext contains:

```
public class UserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }  

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }      

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your `UserDbContext` file look like?

Comment: The error is happening when you initiate a migration, correct?  Did you check the link provided in the error message?  Your startup is configuring your app for runtime, but at design time you need to take different steps to configure the context as identified in the link.

Comment: Make sure you have selected the right project as startup(web)  and set the correct default project (which has your DBContext) in the package manager console

Comment: I added the UserDbContext to the question

Comment: The error happens when I try to scaffold a razor view from my controller.

Comment: I have selected the MVC project as startup project.